# Restrict access to my file or folder in windows server environtment

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Does anybody advice to restrict access to my file or folder in windows server environment?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this and then re-phrasing your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the file or folder, select "Properties", and then check/modify things on the "Security" tab. There are hundreds of how-to articles around on how to manage file permissions in Windows, so if you need more details than what I've given you, I'd suggest that you search around and read through some documentation.